# C-style generic stack implementation in C#

Tags: c#, stack

I saw a nice generic stack implemented in C, in Stanford's CS107 Programming Paradigms course, so I tried to rewrite it in C#:

```
public unsafe static class NativeMemory
{
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", EntryPoint = "memcpy", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, SetLastError = false)]
    public static extern  void* memcpy(void* dest, void* src, UIntPtr count);

    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", EntryPoint = "malloc", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, SetLastError = false)]
    public static extern  void* malloc(UIntPtr count);

    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", EntryPoint = "realloc", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, SetLastError = false)]
    public static extern  void* realloc(void* src, UIntPtr count);

    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", EntryPoint = "free", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, SetLastError = false)]
    public static extern void free(void* src);
}

public unsafe delegate void FreeFunction(void* elemAddr);

public unsafe struct Stack : IDisposable
{
    private readonly int elemSize;
    private readonly FreeFunction freeFunction;
    private int alloclength;
    private void* elems;

    public Stack(int elemSize, FreeFunction freeFunction)
        : this()
    {
        this.elemSize = elemSize;
        this.freeFunction = freeFunction;
        alloclength = 4;
        elems = NativeMemory.malloc((UIntPtr) (elemSize * alloclength));
    }

    public int Count { get; set; }

    public void Push(void* elemAddr)
    {
        if (alloclength == Count)
        {
            Grow();
        }
        NativeMemory.memcpy(((byte*)elems + Count* elemSize), elemAddr, (UIntPtr) elemSize);
        Count++;
    }

    public void Pop(void* elemAddr)
    {
        void* source = ((byte*) elems + (--Count* elemSize));
        NativeMemory.memcpy(elemAddr, source, (UIntPtr)elemSize);
    }

    private void Grow()
    {
        alloclength *= 2;
        elems = NativeMemory.realloc(elems, (UIntPtr) (alloclength* elemSize));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (freeFunction != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
            {
                void* elemAddr = ((byte*) elems + (elemSize * i));
                freeFunction(elemAddr);
            }
        }
        NativeMemory.free(elems);
    }
}

public class Program
{
    private unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (Stack s = new Stack(sizeof (char*), null))
        {
            string[] names = {"rezo", "jack", "andrew"};
            foreach (string n in names)
            {
                fixed (char* ptr = n)
                {
                    char* name = ptr;
                    s.Push(&name);
                }
            }

            while (s.Count > 0)
            {
                char* name;
                s.Pop(&name);
                Console.WriteLine(new string(name));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example of how to store managed objects:

```
private unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var names = new[] {"Brad", "Andrew", "Jon","Melissa"};

    using (Stack stack = new Stack(sizeof(GCHandle), (ptr) =>
    {
        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(new IntPtr(ptr));
        handle.Free();
    }))
    {
        foreach (var name in names)
        {
            GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(name);
            stack.Push(&handle);
        }

        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            GCHandle objHandle;
            stack.Pop(&objHandle);
            Console.WriteLine((string)objHandle.Target);
        }
    }
}
```

What do you think about this? Is there a better way to implement a C-style generic stack in C#?

Answer (score 1):

- <strike>`UIntPtr` is the wrong type to represent a count (it's basically a `void *`). You want `UInt32` or `UInt64` depending on your architecture.</strike>
- `Count` should be `private set`; callers should not be able to change it directly
- Why are `elemsize` and `alloclength` both signed `int`s? Shouldn't they be unsigned? Or at least check the incoming `elemsize` in the constructor?
- I hope that the documentation explains that the `FreeFunction` is for freeing individual elements that the `Stack` owns if it gets destroyed nonempty.
- What's supposed to happen when they `Pop` an empty stack? Right now you get undefined behavior.
- What's supposed to happen if the `malloc()` or `realloc()` fails?

Comment: Signature of memcpy in pinvoke.net had UIntPtr as the count argument. UIntPtr will be 4 bytes on x86 and 8 bytes on x64. You can check it by printing out UIntPtr.Size on x86 and x64.

Comment: That's an..."interesting" design choice for .NET to include both `IntPtr` and the (non-compliant) `UIntPtr` but no `MachineWidthInteger`. Perhaps a `using` directive to indicate the type's actual purpose?